# Data scraping by selenium p tag

Tags: selenium, web, screen-scraping

I searched a lot on the internet. I couldn't find an example similar to the one below. I'm trying to pull text from a web page. There is no location line in the first p tag. The second location section has a location line. When pulling data, I can only pull the contents of the p tag, which is the location row. I cannot pull the contents of the other p tag. I wonder how can I pull the data inside the first and second p tag?

HTML codes of Page Source:

```
<div class=" col-md-8">
    <p>                                                                       
    <i class='fa fa-home main-color'></i> ORHAN MAH.İBRAHİM CAD. NO:35  
    <br>
    <i class='fa fa-phone main-color'></i> 
    <a class="gri" href="tel:0508-2920344">0508-2920344 </a>
    <br /> 
    <i class='fa fa-clock-o main-color'></i> 
    <span class="red">19.01.2022</span>     
    </p>
    <p>
       <i class='fa fa-home main-color'></i> HAZAN MAH.ÖKTEM CAD. NO:13/B                                           
    <br>
    <i class='fa fa-phone main-color'></i> 
    <a class="gri" href="tel:0584 837 23 70">0584 837 23 70 </a>
    <br>
    <i class="fa fa-map-marker main-color"></i> 
    <a class="gri" href="https://www.google.com/maps?q=35.554433,25.887766" target="_blank">Haritada</a>
    <br /> 
    <i class='fa fa-clock-o main-color'></i> 
    <span class="red">20.01.2022</span> 
    </p>
</div>
```

Here is the selenium code I used to pull the data from the HTML source above:

```
item = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("col-md-10")
urls = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class=' col-md-10']/p/a[2]")
for i in zip(item,urls):
    try:            
        address = i[0].find_element_by_css_selector("p").text.split("\n")[:2]
    except:
        address = None
    try:            
        phone = i[0].find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='gri'][1]").text
    except:
        phone = None
    print(address)
    print(phone)
    try:
        url = i[1].get_attribute('href').replace("https://www.google.com/maps?q=","")
    except:
        url = None
    try:            
        date = i[0].find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='red'][1]").text
    except:
        date = None
    print(url)
    print(date)
```

Comment: Can you share a link to that page and clarify what data are you trying to scrape there? Also, what exactly wrong with your current code?

Comment: question is bit confusing, I see a `div` with class `col-md-8` has 2 `p` tag ? do you want to extract the p tag ?

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Use xpath `//div[@class=' col-md-8']/p`. This will return data of both `p` tags.
Then you can perform string operations as per your requirement and use data of each `p` tag using `for` loop

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest. However, nothing has changed. If the location section below is not there, I can pull the data in both p tags. What I want is to print "YOK" in the location section of the first p tag and pull the data from the first and second p tags.
try:
    url = i[1].get_attribute('href').replace("https://www.google.com/maps?q=","")
except:
    url = None

Answer (score 0):

The 1.p tag blog has no location section. The 2.p tag blog has a location section. In the 1.p tag I want, I want to print none instead of the location in the p blog. When I try to pull with zip_longest regularly the location fails to pull.

> #1.p tag block                                                                      
>      ORHAN MAH.İBRAHİM CAD. NO:35  
>     
>      
>     0508-2920344 
>     
>  
>      
>     19.01.2022
>
> #2.p tag block
>         HAZAN MAH.ÖKTEM CAD. NO:13/B                                           
>     
>      
>     0584 837 23 70 
>     
>      
>     Haritada
>     
>  
>      
>     20.01.2022

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think you should include this elaboration in your question.